# Converting coordinates to another form, bug fix

Tags: python, numpy

I am converting coordinates to another format, but there was an error

```
longitude = (lon - 4294967295) / 6356752.3142 * (180/math.pi)
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

I will be grateful for advice

Comment: I see the only minus in this expression, problem is somewhere near

Comment: welcome to SO! can you show us how lon is defined? please [edit] your question to include said part

Comment: Try adding this line before your calculations: `lon = np.array(lon)`

Comment: It looks to me like the lon variable is not a single value but a list or tuple, without more detail about the data it is hard to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `lon` is a list, rather than a numpy array, you can't perform subtraction directly. List comprehension would do it,

```
longitude = [(l - 4294967295) / 6356752.3142 * (180/math.pi) for l in lon]
```

which iterates through `lon` and applies the proper arithmetic on the iterates. Otherwise, using `numpy`, you can do it directly

```
import numpy as np
lon = np.array(lon)
longitude = (lon - 4294967295) / 6356752.3142 * (180/math.pi)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform a mathematical operation like subtraction on a list AKA an iterable type and an integer. You're trying to do:

```
[0,1,2,3,..,n] - 4294967295
```

What you might have meant is:

```
(lon[i] - 4294967295)
```

Where i is the index number for whichever value of the list you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try just converting your `lon` from a list (which doesn't support arithmetic operations like `+`, `-`, etc.) to a numpy array (which *does* support arithmetic operations):

```
lon = np.array(lon)
longitude = (lon - 4294967295) / 6356752.3142 * (180/math.pi)
```